# Sistema de Busca PHP+MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Sou iniciante em PHP e estou com dificuldades em criar a lógica para o sistema de busca que estou implementando. 
Tenho um formulário método GET com três inputs e um select e preciso montar a variável SQL apenas para os GET diferentes de null.

Segue o código que montei:

```
$filtro = array(
'NFe' => $_GET['nfe'],
'NFS' => $_GET['nfse'],
'status' => $_GET['status'],
'vencimento' => $_GET['vencimento']);

foreach($filtro as $chave => $valor){
if(!empty($valor)){
    $sql = " and " .$chave. " = '" .$valor. "'";
}echo $sql; // Aqui ele traz quatro resultados, porem repete os que não estão vazio. 
}
echo $sql; //Aqui ele traz apenas um resultado
```

Comment: Todos os GET serão testados em relação a mesma coluna ou colunas diferentes?

Comment: Luis, são colunas diferentes.

Comment: no foreach estas a subescrever a variavel $sql e o valor anterior não esta ser armazenado tenta `$sql .= "AND coluna = valor";`

Comment: 13dev, Muito obrigado. Deu certo. Havia conseguido utilizado `$sql[ ] = " and " .$chave. " = '" .$valor. "'";` e imprimia assim `$sql[0]. $sql[1]. $sql[2]. $sql[3]; ` Mas a sua forma reduz o código.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boa tarde Rodrigo.
Você pode usar duas estratégias diferentes.
Entendi que são filtros e você pode verificar no código se o campo é nulo e adicionar à sua condição de pesquisa (WHERE) ou você pode montar a condição com todos os campos e testar a condição do campo. Algo como:

Where (@condicao1 is null or campo1 = @condicao1)

Assim, se a @condicao1 for null ele passa e não verifica a comparação com o campo e assim, somente as variáveis não nulas serão comparados com os valores dos campos na condição.

Comment: Segui sua lógica e criei o código acima utilizando foreach. Muito obrigado.

Comment: Se foi útil a resposta, não esquece de marcar clicando na seta para cima!

Answer (score 0):

Rodrigo, teste esta forma e me diz se serve. Na minha imaginação parece funcionar CERCANDO APENAS OS $_GET DEFINIDOS.

```
<?php
$get = [];

if(isset($_GET['nfe']) && !empty($_GET['nfe'])) {
    $nfe = $_GET['nfe'];
    $get[] = "nfe = '$nfe'";
}
if(isset($_GET['nfse']) && !empty($_GET['nfse'])) {
    $nfse = $_GET['nfse'];
    $get[] = "nfse = '$nfse'";
}
if(isset($_GET['status']) && !empty($_GET['status'])) {
    $status = $_GET['status'];
    $get[] = "status = '$status'";
}
if(isset($_GET['vencimento']) && !empty($_GET['vencimento'])) {
    $vencimento = $_GET['vencimento'];
    $get[] = "vencimento = '$vencimento'";
}

$whereCase = join(" AND ", $get);

print $whereCase;
?>
```

Com base na sua lógica ficaria algo assim:

```
<?php
$filtro = array(
    'NFe' => isset($_GET['nfe']) ? $_GET['nfe'] : "",
    'NFS' => isset($_GET['nfse']) ? $_GET['nfse'] : "",
    'status' => isset($_GET['status']) ? $_GET['status'] : "",
    'vencimento' => isset($_GET['vencimento']) ? $_GET['vencimento'] : ""
);

$sql = [];

foreach($filtro as $chave => $valor) {
    if($valor != ""){
        $sql[] = "$chave = '$valor'";
    }
}

$whreCase = join(" AND ", $sql);

echo $whreCase; //Aqui ele traz apenas um resultado
?>
```

Comment: Desculpa a demora. Irei realizar o teste e lhe digo se deu certo.